# How to pass dafault values to the NULL or undefined fields?

Tags: javascript

I have small requirement, here I'm getting values to the table dynamically. Some times few fields returns some null/blank values. If it gives null values showing error message like

```
"worderId[i].childNodes[0] is undefined"
```

Please help me  how to assign some default values to the null values.
Here I tried some code,

```
if(worderId.length>0)
{

WOTableData= "<table cellpadding='0' cellspacing='1' border='0' width=100% class='display' id='WOData' ><thead><tr id='row1'><th>&nbsp;</th><th>worderId</th><th>wostatus</th></thead><tbody>";
var technologyImage="";
for(i=0;i<worderId.length;i++)
    {   

        WOTableData=WOTableData+"<tr title='"+worderId[i].childNodes[0].nodeValue+"</td><td>"+ worderId[i].childNodes[0].nodeValue+"</td><td>"+wostatus[i].childNodes[0].nodeValue+"</td></tr>";                                            

    }
WOTableData=WOTableData+"</tbody></table>";


document.getElementById("WODataDiv").innerHTML = WOTableData;
}
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add a simple condition in your for loop to check for that value.

```
for(i=0;i<worderId.length;i++)
{   

    if (!worderId[i].childNodes || !worderId[i].childNodes.length || !worderId[i].childNodes[0].nodeValue) {
        worderId[i].childNodes = [{nodeValue: "some_default_value"}];
    }

    WOTableData=WOTableData+"<tr title='"+worderId[i].childNodes[0].nodeValue+"</td><td>"+ worderId[i].childNodes[0].nodeValue+"</td><td>"+wostatus[i].childNodes[0].nodeValue+"</td></tr>";                                            

}
```

Comment: I added below code in my page, but still issue existing,                           if (!worderId[i].childNodes || !worderId[i].childNodes.length || !worderId[i].childNodes[0].nodeValue) {
        worderId[i].childNodes = "---";
    }

Comment: here is the issue "worderId[i].childNodes[0] is undefined"